# How to add bottom half circle overlay on circle?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create something like this, to add a half overlay circle and add text over it.

I have a full circle with Image, But not sure how to add the `Edit` part on it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't really looking for a half circle overlay, you are looking for something like the bottom 45% of the main circle to have an overlay.

Both the photo and the overlay look to me as though they are (semantically) backgrounds so this snippet puts the overlay as a linear gradient image first - it will then come 'in front' of anything following, and then the actual image.

I am assuming that the word 'Edit' is important for the user to know about, so for screen reader users it needs to be in the DOM, not in a pseudo element.

```css
div {
  width: 20vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0 65%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 65% 100%), url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Edit</span></div>
```

Obviously you'll want to adjust the exact positionings to get the look you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the edit part using pseudo classes (:before, :after)

```css
:before{
   content: 'Edit';
   height: ;
   width: ;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: I need a small half circle at bottom of the full circle also with `Edit` text.